# Laravel: how to write query without a target

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to create a query first and then assign it to a select?

**For Example**

```
$queryWithoutTarget = new Builder();

$queryWithoutTarget->where('x','y')->whereNull('z');

$workersQuery = Worker::select();

// I know this is Totally wrong, because queryWithoutTarget is not a parameter of $workersQuery
$workersQuery = $workersQuery->queryWithoutTarget;
```

I'm trying to encapsulate the query in functions and then execute them to any model or table

Answer (score 0):

No, first you use `$queryWithoutTarget` as a variable (at the first and third row), then you use it as a function (at the 8th row (`{...}->queryWithoutTarget`)

**Edit:** If you override the `Builder` class then it may be possible. Open has maybe endless possibilities. But it's up to you to make overrides instead of additional lines in the controller

Comment: It's just an example of what I'm looking for, that's why I write a comment, to avoid this observations

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope. Scope is just a convenience method you can add to your model which encapsulates the syntax used to execute a query

Create your scope trait

```
namespace App\Models\Worker\Traits;

/**
 * Class WorkerScope.
 */
trait WorkerScope
{
    /**
     * @param $query
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('x','y')->whereNull('z');
    }
}
```

Implement your scope on model

```
use App\Models\Worker\Traits\WorkerScope;

/**
 * Class Worker.
 */
class Worker extends Model
{
    use WorkerScope;

    ...
}
```

With the scope defined, you can execute it like

```
$workersQuery = Worker::active()->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but using scopes I need to know from the beginning in which model I'm going to use the query right?

Comment: That's why i use a trait. so, you can excecute the scope in any model that you want to implement it. You can use scope with relationship like Project::workers()->active()->get() and you can use a parameter inside a scope too